# Error while attempting to Implement Preemptive SJF in C

Tags: c, algorithm, scheduling

I've implemented a PSJF algorithm, however for some reason
the code here:

```
if (!tasks[i].completed && tasks[i].arrival_time <= current_time && tasks[i].burst_time < shortest_job_burst)
            {
                shortest_job_index = i;
                shortest_job_burst = tasks[i].burst_time;
                found_job = 1;
            }
```

and all code following it does not function. I figure it may be some type of error with the if statement logic, but still unsure about what specifically is causing the block.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAX_TASKS 50
#define TIME_QUANTUM 4

typedef struct
{
    char name[10];
    int arrival_time;
    int burst_time;
    int remaining_time;
    int waiting_time;
    int completed;
} Task;

Task tasks[MAX_TASKS];
Task ready_queue[MAX_TASKS];
int front = -1, rear = -1;

void enqueue(Task task)
{
    if (front == -1)
    {
        front = 0;
    }
    rear++;
    ready_queue[rear] = task;
}

Task dequeue()
{
    Task task = ready_queue[front];
    if (front == rear)
    {
        front = -1;
        rear = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        front++;
    }
    return task;
}

int is_empty()
{
    return front == -1;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *input_file = fopen("TaskSpec.txt", "r");
    FILE *output_file = fopen("Output.txt", "w");
    // load variables here (not displayed)
    // PSJF
// Initialize variables
int current_time = 0;
int total_waiting_time = 0;

fprintf(output_file, "PSJF\nExecution Sequence\n");

int remaining_tasks_psjf = num_tasks;

// Check for proper initialization and bounds
if (num_tasks > 0)
{
    // PSJF
    while (remaining_tasks_psjf > 0)
    {
        int shortest_job_index = -1;
        int shortest_job_burst = INT_MAX; // Initialize to maximum possible value
        int found_job = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < num_tasks; i++)
        {
            if (!tasks[i].completed && tasks[i].arrival_time <= current_time && tasks[i].burst_time < shortest_job_burst)
            {
                shortest_job_index = i;
                shortest_job_burst = tasks[i].burst_time;
                found_job = 1;
            }
        }

        if (found_job)
        {
            fprintf(output_file, "%s\t%d\t", tasks[shortest_job_index].name, current_time);
            if (tasks[shortest_job_index].burst_time <= TIME_QUANTUM)
            {
                current_time += tasks[shortest_job_index].burst_time;
                fprintf(output_file, "%d\n", current_time);
                tasks[shortest_job_index].waiting_time = current_time - tasks[shortest_job_index].arrival_time - tasks[shortest_job_index].burst_time; // waiting time calculation corrected
                total_waiting_time += tasks[shortest_job_index].waiting_time; // accumulate total waiting time
                tasks[shortest_job_index].completed = 1;
                remaining_tasks_psjf--;
            }
            else
            {
                current_time += TIME_QUANTUM;
                fprintf(output_file, "%d\n", current_time);
                tasks[shortest_job_index].burst_time -= TIME_QUANTUM;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // No eligible tasks found, move to the next time unit
            current_time++;
        }
    }

    fprintf(output_file, "Waiting Time of Each Task\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_tasks; i++)
    {
        fprintf(output_file, "%s\t%d\n", tasks[i].name, tasks[i].waiting_time);
    }
    float average_waiting_time = (float)total_waiting_time / num_tasks;
    fprintf(output_file, "Average Waiting Time\n%.2f\n\n", average_waiting_time);
}
else
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: No tasks to schedule.\n");
}
    fclose(output_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Tried to implement a PSJF algorithm from pseudocode, appears to not run after a particular segment of code. Program has to be quit forcefully, and does not complete.

Comment: Use a debugger to print out the values of variables at different lines, you will find the issue.